# Asp.Net label text resets when go to back page through browser back button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hello i am working on ASP.NET
I have a label called lblReport and 10 links, when i click on a link lblReport text is set to Report name initially label has no text and page also has a button. when i click on button it go to report page,
when i go to back page from report page lblReport text is get reset.

what i need is on going to back page lblReport text should be set to selected report name

here is javascript function

```
function fun(s, rpt) {

    document.getElementById("lblId").value = s;
    document.getElementById("lblReport").innerHTML = rpt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden field to store lblReport text as hidden field doesn't get refreshed on postback.

Comment: i want that lblReport text should be same after going back to previous page.i have used hidden field to store that report name and label to show report name. when click on button it shows report after going back on page but label text get reset is the problem

Comment: Well, it should not reset if you are using hidden field to store and show the value. Use breakpoint and display the hidden field value in alert. May be this way you'll able to know if the value is getting stored in hidden field or not.